# Pronunciation rule if two consecutive consonants followed by a vowel

Tags: pronunciation

The person is pronouncing the number 80 in [this](http://f.lui.li/get_587_b75c.html) sentence as /neiti/ for the number 184.

Is it a common rule to elide the last one if there are two consecutive consonants followed by a vowel just like this case one hundred "and eighty"?

Which pronunciation rule she is using?

Comment: That sounds more British than American.  $184 for a 12 month period.

Comment: but why the eighty sounds different with this one http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/eighty

Comment: It doesn't sound different.(in a meaningful way)

Comment: Pronunciation varies greatly from person to person, region to region: http://www.forvo.com/word/eighty/#en

Comment: It sounds to me /neiti/, where does the sound /n/ come from?

Comment: She actually is saying "One hundred and eighty four dollars."  The "n" you are hearing is from the "and" from which the "d" has been elided to become "an"

Comment: Got it. Is it a common rule to elide the last consonant if there are two consecutive ones followed by a vowel just like this case "and eighty"?

Comment: It depends on the consonants: *winner* instead of *winter* is common in the U.S. (the 't' is often dropped in words containing 'nt' followed by an unstressed vowel), and dropping the 'd' from the word *and* is quite common, but nobody says *disasser* instead of *disaster*.

Comment: It's nothing to do with *"followed by a vowel"*. Lots of consonants (and vowels) are elided in common speech, and downgrading **and** to **ən** is an *exceptionally* common case in point. So much so that the [stock meal among the working classes in Great Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_and_chips) is frequently even *written* as ["fish n chips"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fish+n+chips%22&aq=f&oq=%22fish+n+chips%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.1278j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ("frequently" there means 3.5M times on Google alone! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a common rule to elide the last consonant if there are two consecutive ones followed by a vowel?

It's a good deal more complicated than that. As Peter Shor tells you, “It depends on the consonants”; it also depends on the surrounding vowels, on where the stress falls,and why, on where word and syllable boundaries fall, on local practice (dialect), and on individual practice (idiolect).

In your example, for instance, (at least) three principles are operating. (I'm illustrating with US pronunciations, but I don't think that British pronunciation in these instances would call for different arguments.)

- English doesn't much like ‘closed’ syllables—syllables which end on a consonant. In speech we prefer our syllables as ‘open’ as possible: the happiest ending is a vowel, next is a more vowel-like consonant (a continuant), next is a voiced stop, and last is a voiceless stop. Other things being equal, a consonant or consonant cluster at the end of a syllable tends to be reduced towards vowelness.

  For instance, in speaking *last man*, the voiceless stop /t/ will tend to be dropped: /læs mæn/. In speaking *canned peas*, the voiced stop /d/ will tend to be dropped: /kæn piz/.
- However, if the following syllable begins with a vowel, the consonant or cluster can be ‘tied’ to it, leaving the preceding syllable ‘open’: *last ever* becomes /læ stɛvr/. But this only works to the extent that the tied consonant cluster is acceptable at the beginning of a syllable. /st/ is a common syllable onset, but English syllables never begin with /nd/; so in speaking *canned okra* the cluster is split, leaving /kæn doʊkrə/.
- That would lead you to expect *and eighty* to be pronounced as /æn deɪɾɪ/. But in practice, unstressed *and* is almost always reduced to mere /n/. In this instance that principle comes into play **first**, before the liaison takes place. Consequently, you end up with /neɪɾɪ/.